# Remove new skype ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, uninstall, skype

I have two versions of Skype on my OS (Ubuntu 14.04).

I was able to remove the old one (v4.3) using the command:

```
 sudo apt-get purge skype
```

But how do I remove the latest version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue the following command:

`sudo apt-get purge skypeforlinux`